# Replicating byte string creation done in Javascript into Python 2.7

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, byte

I have a function I am mapping from Javascript:

```
var commandBytes = [4,1,0,0,0,0, Math.floor(224 + (52/16)), 52 % 16];
```

...this is how I have in Python:

```
data = bytearray([4,1,0,0,0,0, 224 + 52 // 16, 52 % 16])
```

...this is what the output looks like in IDLE:

```
bytearray(b'\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe3\x04')
```

...this is what the original output looks like when output by Javascript to the Command Prompt window:

```
<Buffer 04 01 00 00 00 00 e3 04>
```

...first issue I have is the bytes in IDLE seem to be printed in hex rather than actual numbers. Second is, even though I know my connection to the machine I am passing the command to is good as I am getting a response, the command itself does not work.

What do I need to change so that my Python output replicates my Javascript output?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you care how it is displayed on your terminal - it looks like it has equivalent data. If you really want it to display the same then extend the bytearray() and implement your own `__str__()` and/or `__repr__()`. You haven't provided enough information to help with why the command isn't working.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to replicate? What are "actual numbers"? Why is formatting and issue? I don't really understand your question here.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change how it is printed, either by creating your own `print_function` or by extending `bytearray` and implementing `__str__()` and/or `__repr__()`, e.g.:

```py
class ByteArray(bytearray):
    def __str__(self):
        return '<Buffer {}>'.format(' '.join(format(x, '02x') for x in self))

In []:
b = ByteArray([4,1,0,0,0,0, 224 + 52 // 16, 52 % 16])
print(b)

Out[]:
<Buffer 04 01 00 00 00 00 e3 04>
```